# The new item is added twice at the end of the column

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am trying to update the store column by adding new item (string) to the end of the column,
But what happens is the new item is added twice at the end of the column, This is the code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

$item = 'item_name';
$store = $row['store'];
$newstore = $store . '|' . $item;

echo 'newstore : ' . $newstore . '<br>'; // It looks normal : store|item
    
$sql = "UPDATE users SET store='" . $newstore . "' WHERE username='" . $row['username'] .  "'";
$conn->query($sql); 
}
```

In in the database I find: **store|item|item**

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: Do you have users with duplicate usernames? Are you 100% sure the code isn't executed twice?

Comment: @Dharman I will only use the code for one time only (by me)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson no, no users with  duplicate usernames, and yes i'am sure that the code isn't executed twice

Comment: Everything was fine, I think the problem was with the php,

I used node js and everything worked just right

Comment: Then if it's only going to be used one time and by you, **then you must use parameterized queries as I have said before**. There is literally no excuse why you would ever want to do it any other way. You should always use prepared statements and bind your data separately.

Comment: @Dharman It meets my needs and I wrote the code a little bit faster (tests in the localhost) 

In production always use a filters and prepare stmt


anyway thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than reading the entire table and looping through it with PHP, run just a single UPDATE query to concatenate the extra data onto the column.:

```
$item = 'item_name';
$query = "UPDATE users SET store=concat(store,'|','$item')";
$result = $conn->query($query);
```

Note: this form is potentially open to SQL injection if you can't trust the value in `$item`. You'd do better to use a prepared query if that's the case.

Comment: I have to loop with php because I will add costume conditions later, do you notice any problem in the code?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code. Are you sure the database contains what you think it does? Have you run the query before? In any case, depending on the complexity of your conditions, you can build them into your UPDATE query.

Comment: It's weird, I tried your code and got the same error

Comment: Let's assume it can't be trusted

Comment: @Strawberry Let's not make unwarranted assumptions.